# NOt getting the array - PHP JSON Explode

Tags: php, arrays, json, explode

I am trying to explode the JSON file below with the 2 arrays but keep getting an output of..

```
Array
(
[0] =>
)
Array
(
[0] =>
)
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

```js
[0]=>
array(2) {
["question_id"]=>
string(2) "88"
["weight"]=>
string(1) "5"
}
[1]=>
array(2) {
["question_id"]=>
string(2) "89"
["weight"]=>
string(1) "5"
```

```
$quest_id = $data["question_id"];
$quest_points = $data["weight"];

$quest_id_array = explode(" ,", $quest_id);
$quest_points_array = explode(" ,", $quest_points);

print_r($quest_id_array);
print_r($quest_points_array);
```

Comment: _“I am trying to explode the JSON file below”_ - what JSON, what file? You have shown neither in your code.

Comment: please dont down vote the question without letting the op explain themselves in response to comments, the current question is as well as the op can post probably and they need help with it, once they reply for what the file was and the rest of the things that make the question clear, dont down vote it. They can even take a full day or 3 days to come back to see comments (i have done that too yes), even till then dont down vote, this question remaining here as 0 votes wont break SO servers neither will the quality get effected.

Comment: thank you user734028, a student and still very new to this. I appreciate that, and also thank you Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$data` is the array you show at the top, it's not an array containing comma-separated strings. It's a 2-dimensional array, so you need to loop over it and push the values onto the new arrays.

```
$quest_id_array = [];
$quest_points_array = [];
foreach ($data as $val) {
    $quest_id_array[] = $val['question_id'];
    $quest_points_array[] = $val['weight'];
}
```